# find_by inside a scope is firing 2 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using Rails 4.2.3 and ruby 2.2.1

I have written a scope in roles model as follows:

app/models/role.rb

```
scope :default, -> { find_by(default: true) }
```

Now when I run

```
> Role.default

#this is the output I got.

Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`default` = 1 LIMIT 1 
Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
=> []
```

As you can see this fires 2 queries and returns wrong result.

I tried with class method instead of scope

```
def self.default
  self.find_by(default: true)
end
```

Now when I run

```
Role.default

#this is the output I got

Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`default` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

With class method find_by is working properly.

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `find_by` inside a scope - `find_by` actually executes a database query.

You should only be using methods that return further scopes, for example `where`, `limit`, `order` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord, the object relational mapping system built into Rails, provides you with a set of methods to use in your scopes to abstract out the database queries.  Those methods are listed here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database

In your case, you will want to use the `where` query.

`scope :default, -> { where(default: true) }`