# Is it possible to use find_by within a Rails scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

It seems that it is not possible to use `find_by` within a scope in Rails with Mongoid. Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find\_by inside a scope is firing 2 queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329554/find-by-inside-a-scope-is-firing-2-queries)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329554/find-by-inside-a-scope-is-firing-2-queries

Comment: What does your scope look like? What happens when you try to use it? Keep in mind that `find_by` isn't a query building method and scopes are for building queries so `find_by` doesn't really fit in a scope.

Comment: @muistooshort - Yes, this makes sense. Thanks.